# Software for cluster analysis of dichotomous data

Tags: clustering, binary-data, software

can anybody recommend software for cluster analysis of dichotomous data (using appropriate coefficients, e.g. from Finch, 2005 [1](http://www.jds-online.com/files/JDS-192.pdf))? I have access to Statistica but it seems to me that it is not possible to analyze binary answers there.